# How to convert UTC to EST in Java

Tags: java, timezone, utc

Morning all,

We just had our vendor do an upgrade and converted everything to UTC, but the export we get isn't converting to EST. This is causing issues.

I'm trying to determine how to alter this template to give us the right time zone. I think changing the datetimeformatter section would fix it, but nothing I've tried has worked.

Here is the ftl template file:

```
<#ftl output_format="XML">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<#assign dateTimeFormatter = objConstructor("java.text.SimpleDateFormat","MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") />
<#assign targetDate = dateTimeFormatter.format( ros08.date.toGregorianCalendar().getTime() ) />
<Data>
   <Date>${targetDate}</Date>
   <Headers></Headers>
   <Records>
   <#assign records = ros08.records.records >
   <#list records as ch>
      <#assign startDate = dateTimeFormatter.format( ch.staffingStartDt.toGregorianCalendar().getTime() ) />
      <#assign endDate = dateTimeFormatter.format( ch.staffingEndDt.toGregorianCalendar().getTime() ) />
      <Record>
         <ShiftAbrvCh>${ch.shiftAbrvCh!""}</ShiftAbrvCh>
         <AgencyAbrvCh>${ch.agencyAbrvCh!""}</AgencyAbrvCh>
         <RegionAbrvCh>${ch.regionAbrvCh!""}</RegionAbrvCh>
         <StationAbrvCh>${ch.stationAbrvCh!""}</StationAbrvCh>
         <PUnitAbrvCh>${ch.PUnitAbrvCh!""}</PUnitAbrvCh>
         <RscEmployeeIDCh>${ch.rscEmployeeIDCh!""}</RscEmployeeIDCh>
         <PosJobAbrvCh>${ch.posJobAbrvCh!""}</PosJobAbrvCh>
         <WstatAbrvCh>${ch.wstatAbrvCh!""}</WstatAbrvCh>
         <WstatIsWorkingGm>${ch.wstatIsWorkingGm?c}</WstatIsWorkingGm>
         <StaffingDurationIn_0_0___>${ch.staffingDurationIn?string["0.00"]}</StaffingDurationIn_0_0___>
         <StaffingStartDt_mm_dd_yyyy_hh_nn_ss>${startDate}</StaffingStartDt_mm_dd_yyyy_hh_nn_ss>
         <StaffingEndDt_mm_dd_yyyy_hh_nn_ss>${endDate}</StaffingEndDt_mm_dd_yyyy_hh_nn_ss>
         <DisplayOrderGm>${ch.displayOrderGm}</DisplayOrderGm>
         <StaffingNoteVc>${ch.staffingNoteVc!""}</StaffingNoteVc>
         <StaffingDetailCh>${ch.staffingDetailCh!""}</StaffingDetailCh>
         <PUnitNameCh>${ch.PUnitNameCh!""}</PUnitNameCh>
      </Record>
   </#list>
   </Records>
</Data>
```

Comment: Now is an excellent time to upgrade your infrastructure to UTC as well. Don't forget to call `dateTimeFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch shouldn't it be `getTimeZone("EST")` as they are trying to convert it to EST?

Comment: Not certain. The default timezone of a `SimpleDateFormat` is the system timezone. I'm assuming it's already in EST, and the remote side is sending UTC. Thus the values are "wrong". If so, this is how you fix it.

Comment: So what does this whole line need to be? I've tried inserting the set timezone code, but not sure where: <#assign dateTimeFormatter = objConstructor("java.text.SimpleDateFormat","MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") />

Comment: Or do I just add this after? dateTimeFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))

Comment: <#assign dateTimeFormatter = objConstructor("java.text.SimpleDateFormat","MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") /> dateTimeFormatter .setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST")) , or do I need another <#assign etc, or do I need to put this before the />?

Comment: Also, the system is UTC, the receiving software needs it to be EST. Hope that helps.

Comment: Don't use "EST".  Use "America/New_York".  (assuming USA)

Comment: As an aside, can you avoid using `SimpleDateFormat`? It’s an old and troubesome class that was replaced 7 years ago through [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Seconding, @MattJohnson-Pint, even for "UTC", you should use "Etc/UTC".